# How to upload images to the disk drive of server?

Tags: php

I am making a [Tuition Teacher](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher/signup.html) finding website.I have made a sign up form. I would like to add a profile picture option to the form.

Here is the code for it,

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

How do I store the image in the disk drive of the server computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use php  `move_uploaded_file`

```
<?php
       if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
          $errors= array();
          $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
          $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
          echo "Success";

       }
    ?>
    <html>
       <body>

          <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <input type="file" name="image" />
             <input type="submit"/>
          </form>

       </body>
    </html>
```

> move_uploaded_file(file,newloc)
>
> file:- Specifies the file to be moved
>
> newloc:- Specifies the new location for the file

Comment: It gives me the following error,
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/1.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sadathr/inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher/receive.php on line 33
`

Comment: creat folder **images** inside **tuitionteacher** folder  like that :-**tuitionteacher/images**

Comment: It works just for one time. I ran the script again but the image did not got uploaded.

Comment: <?php
       if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
          $errors= array();
          $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
          $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
          $extension  = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          $new= rand(0000,9999);
          $file_name=$new.'.'.$extension;
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
          echo "Success";

       }
    ?>

Comment: Now it gives me the following warning,
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/8486.image/png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sadathr/inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher/receive.php on line 38`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93131/discussion-between-rahautos-and-fahad-uddin).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your form should have attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. You can also use `copy(file,to_file)`.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

```
if (strlen($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) > 0) {

    $path="path/to/new-location/IMAGENAME-With-Extension";

    copy($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$path);
}
```